# The volumes always mount to the /root/ not /crawler/ I specified

Tags: docker

I have no idea why the the external folder always mount to **/root/**,

I've alreay specified the mount point is **/crawler/**

## end of dockerfile

```
#====================================
# Scripts to run Selenium Standalone
#====================================
EXPOSE 4444
#USER root
WORKDIR  /crawler
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
#USER seluser
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - 4444:4444
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./:/crawler/
  ports:
    - 5900:5900
  links:
    - hub:hub
```

Comment: How do you know it mounts to `/root/`?

Comment: when I attached to the container, the current folder in the host is mounted to the `/root`

Comment: You are root when you enter the container,  so PWD shows /root

Comment: Not related to `PWD`,  i meant the `current folder` is mount to `/root/`  in the container. but i didn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work accessing another directory (home in my example below).

Just running from docker cli without compose I changed the working directory from the command line, like so:

`docker run -d -P --name selenium-hub -w /home selenium/hub`

I then attached

`docker exec -it selenium-hub bash`

And ended up in home

`seluser@238c1323bab7:/home$ pwd
/home`

So, as long as the directory 'crawler' was created via the docker file you should change your docker compose to something like this below

`hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - 4444:4444
  working_dir: /crawler
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./:/crawler/
  ports:
    - 5900:5900
  links:
    - hub:hub`